# Reason for: Trying to get property of non-object in php

Tags: php

```
$EODQuery = "SELECT * FROM EOD WHERE Symbol LIKE '$start' LIMIT 1 OFFSET $limit";

$EODRes = $mysqli->query($EODQuery);
```

I get an error, but not when i directly query the database.

```
  <?php $i = 0; while($i <= 4) { $EODRow = getEOD("A%",$i); $i++; echo $EODRow;  } ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get in which line and which code does work? Where does `$mysqli` come from?

Comment: Also, show the exact error, and the code that's generating it (the code you posted will not generate that error, there needs to be more)...

Comment: Either you've not instantiated a mysqli object, in which case $mysqli is null and has no `->query()` method, or the query itself failed, and $EODRes is actually a mysqli error object, not a query result, having no `->fetch()` method.

Comment: @ircmaxell: the resultset line i.e. the 2nd line in my questio generates: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\getEODRow.php on line 7

Comment: @Pekka: that comes from a config.php file that i have included at the top. the second line generates: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\getEODRow.php on line 7

Comment: @Kuttu: That's the not error you posted in the title.  Please edit the question to include the **exact** error messages and the relevant code that's throwing them.

Comment: @Marc: i have instantiated...

Comment: Then did you check if the connection to MySQL actually succeeded? If it didn't, `$mysqli = new mysqli()` doesn't return a database handle, it returns an error object.

Comment: i use the same header for many files. I haven't received ny error

Comment: Oh wait, it says property, not method. In this case, my answer below is totally wrong. I guess it DOES have to do with your query. Please check whether the variables $start and $limit actually contain the data that you expect.

Comment: @ Dave: yep... if i return the query statement from the function and use it in the db directly it works fie...

Comment: @Kuttu: I still don't get it. You say the `$mysqli->query()` call is not in a function, but your (updated) code shows you call a function `getEOD()`, which I guess contains the above code. If this is correct, try the `global $mysqli` statement from my answer.

Comment: @Dave: thanx.. what i  meant was that the call was not inside ny function.. sorry, i'll try...

Comment: Hi all. Thanx.. working fine.. had to include global $mysqli..

Comment: Which goes to show that you need to show the full code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first look it seems like you have forgotten to instantiate $mysqli, that leads to $mysqli not being an object, so you cant execute the query() method.

Comment: i have included a header file that instantiates $mysqli

Comment: It would be helpful to see the whole code. The included php file and the file which executes $mysqli->query(). Without seeing the code it's just quessing

Comment: @kalkin: the function call: <?php $i = 0; while($i <= 4) { $EODRow = getEOD("A%",$i); $i++; echo $EODRow;  } ?>

Comment: @kalkin: the included file works for other queries, in other pages, too.. That might not b a problem, I suppose

Comment: @Kuttu but it also might be the problem. Please show the full code. You are not within a function with this?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mistyped the var name in your code or something like this? Because it really looks like $mysqli isn't an object in this context.

Comment: @kalkin: I had to include global mysqli; inside my uffunc defn

Comment: So you solved the problem? If so we would found the error if you just posted the whole code, but if you can't post it because of NDA I can understand

Answer (score 2):

Your error message has nothing to do with the query itself. What's happening is this: You're calling a method `query()` on the `$mysqli` object - however, PHP thinks that it's not actually an object.

The reason for this can be:

- You forgot to create this object (See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php). Here's an example:

  ```
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
  ```
- You mistyped the variable name, so your mysqli object is actually called something else.
- The code you show is within a function or a method, but your `$mysqli` object is in the global scope. In this case, you should "load" it into the function scope, like this:

  ```
  function doStuff() {
      global $mysqli;

      $mysqli->query(...);
  }
  ```

  For more information regarding variable scope, see this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I've just added a third suggestion of what could be wrong.. does this help your problem?

Comment: @Dave: it is in the main(), not inside a func - local

Comment: Or the connect call failed and `$mysqli` is an error object instead of a `mysqli` handle.

Comment: @Dave: thanx mate.. working fine.. is that similar to including the file within the func definition?

Comment: @Kuttu "similar" maybe, but not quite (Functions and classes would still be global, not local to your function). I've attached a link about variable scope to the answer, please read that to find out more :)